# Excel Formula for Price Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

"anyone know what is the formula for D17?

if i input B17 as Start and C17 as End

1200-2000 = will cost 800*300 = 240,000

2000-3000 = will cost 1000*400 = 400,000

3000-3500 = will cost 500*500 = 250,000

240k + 400k + 250k = 890k

[image]

Comment: ThIs is going to be much easier to solve with a helper column as column E in your lookup table.  It may be possible without, especially with Excel O365, but it will end up being  long complicated formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP in a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(B14-A14,,A14),A2:C11,3))
```

[image]

If one does not have SEQUENCE then use ROW with two INDEXES:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A14):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B14-1)),A2:C11,3))
```

[image]

Comment: both are works!! thank you!!..